# Is it possible to invocate multiple machines in one Ragel file?

Tags: c++, ragel

I'm creating a fairly simple parser which has no recursive structures or anything too challenging.

What I would like to do is when I run in to a "command" I would like to call a separate parsing function (in host language) such as parseCommandType1 which would then have a separate return type etc. depending on the command. That function would then invocate its own Ragel machine for parsing the contents of the command.

If I want to do all of this in one Ragel parser the logic gets very ugly very quickly because based on the command type I need to interpret the data differently and create some different type derived objects.

The "submachines" are also very simple and there would be quite a few of them so I would definitely not want to split them to separate files. My current implementation that I'm trying to clean up has like 200-300 lines so splitting it to like ten files seems a bit inconvenient.

So the question is can I somehow invocate/create/instantiate multiple Ragel machines in one file? The machines can have a name but there seems to be no way to call that name, just include it to different machines so to me it kinda looks like you can only have one machine per file?

Is there any other neat way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Something like this works for me. Admittedly it can get pretty verbose if you have many function definitions.

```
%%{

    machine Machine1;

    main := ... ;

}%%

%% write data nofinal;

void machine1_func(char *p, size_t p_len) {
    int cs;
    char *pe = p + p_len; 

%% write init;
%% write exec;

} //Only one blank line between next ragel machine definition or it doesn't seem to find the next definition. 

%%{

    machine Machine2;

    main := ... ;

}%%

%% write data nofinal;

void machine2_func(char *p, size_t p_len) {
    int cs;
    char *pe = p + p_len; 

    %% write init;
    %% write exec;

}
```